# Best workflow for working in a feature branch when there are changes in the master branch

Tags: git, github

So i am currently working on a feature branch for a specific task. Now in the meantime others have raised some PRs and they have been merged into the master branch. Now what should be the workflow here so that I can have those changes show up in my feature branch too so that while making the PR i don't have to face any problems?

Comment: It's a team choice but if you're alone working in your feature branch, maybe the best option is to rebase your branch on top of master...

Comment: I tried to do a rebase after pulling the changes into the master and it showed up an error which made the branch be like 2 commits ahead and 2 commits behind master

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two options:

1. Merge - With your feature branch checked out, use `git merge` to merge the latest `master` branch into your branch.  If there are any merge conflicts, you will have to resolve them and finalize the commit.  The advantages of merging are that all of your original commits are kept in the branch as they were.  The disadvantage is that the commit history becomes more complicated, since your branch will include additional paths in the commit history.  Info on merging is here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge
2. Rebase - With your feature branch checked out, use `git rebase`.  This approach attempts to modify each of your branches commits in order to incorporate all of the changes made to the 'master' branch that you are rebasing onto.  This advantage of this approach is that your branch will have a single path of commits leading back to the latest `master` branch commit.  The disadvantage, is that the physical commits that you originally created will no longer be part of your branch.  Info on rebasing is here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase.

If you choose to rebase, you may want to create a new branch at the branch that you plan to rebase in order to maintain a link to your original commits, just in case something goes awry.

[image]